# Selenium python chrome webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium to scrape some data from mouser.com website but after sending some data in the search bar. The website results in access denied, I need help to bypass it. I tried using an agent but the same thing.

[image]

```
import time
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/amuri/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/site-packages/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(1)

#def get_comp_type(comp_pn):
url ='https://www.mouser.com/'
driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".form-control.headerSearchBox.search-input.js-search-autosuggest.as-input")))
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".form-control.headerSearchBox.search-input.js-search-autosuggest.as-input")
elem.click()
elem.send_keys("myString")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Don't send too many request in short duration of time. Many website think its a bot and block it. What i can suggest is after the result came.. yo better do some activity like scroll down and scroll up .. wait there for sometime, and then try new URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Option
options = Options()
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
print(user_agent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/amuri/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0/site-packages/chromedriver.exe',options=options)
```

You didn't use your useragent anywhere in options. ALso you need to set javascript and cookies as well.